# PHP Displaying Order Item ". $i ."

Tags: php

I am trying to display the values of `$i` in my shopping cart so it prints out:

```
Order item 1
Order item 2 
etc..
```

Since my index starts at 0, I don't want it to say Order item 0.

I've tried

```
$cartoutput .= " <tr><td width='20%'> Order Item ". $i+1." </td>
```

but that is not working.

Comment: That will work just fine if the string is properly quoted all the way to the end `$cartoutput .= " <tr><td width='20%'> Order Item ". $i+1." </td>";` How is it failing for you?

Comment: Alternatively, start `$i` from 1 instead of 0. What is the loop code that sets and increments `$i`?

Comment: $i starts at 0. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems. Doing

```
$cartoutput .= "text". $i+1."text";
```

1. since there is no separator between `1` and `.`, PHP expects a floating number, like `1.234`... and gives an error since there is no operator (`.` being the decimal point) after `1.` before text.
2. `+` is for adding numbers, `.` is the strings concatenation operator: since they have the same precedence and their associativity is left to right, having a space between `1` and `.`,

PHP would do

```
(("text" . $i) + 1) . "text"
```

that returns `(0 + 1) . "text"`, ie `"1text"` (since `"text123"` is evaluated as `0`, if `$i` is 123)

The best in order to be safe, is to allow PHP to do an addition between `$i` and `1` by inserting parentheses:

```
   $cartoutput .= "text" . ($i+1) . "text";
```

ie in your case

```
$cartoutput .= " <tr><td width='20%'> Order Item " . ($i+1) . " </td> ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Add parenthesis to the sum:

```
$cartoutput .= " <tr><td width='20%'> Order Item ". ($i+1) . " </td> ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple `if` condition

```
if($i > 0)
$cartoutput .= " <tr><td width='20%'> Order Item ". $i+1." </td>
```

But you use `$i+1` so if even you start with `0-based` index then it should echo `Order item 1`

Answer (score 0):

What is that outputting?

Try the following;

```
$j = $i + 1;
$cartoutput .= '<tr><td width="20%"> Order Item ' . $j . '</td></tr>';
```